# No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?

Tags: jestjs, expo

I'm getting these warnings when I run my expo / jest project and I'm not sure why, seemed to not come up when googled.

```
console.warn
    The "EXNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that expo-modules-core's native code is linked properly

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-modules-core/src/NativeModulesProxy.native.ts:54:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-modules-core/src/index.ts:4:1)

  console.warn
    No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-constants/src/Constants.ts:32:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-asset/src/PlatformUtils.ts:2:1)
```

Comment: Did you resolved this?

Comment: Have you found the answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this error in a test (jest), and I had to install `jest-expo` and change `preset` in the jest config to mock out expo stuff for jest and fix this.

See details here: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/testing-with-jest/#installation

Answer (score 2):

If you using any Expo library in your project important thing you need is **expo** and **expo-core-modules** packages in your package.json file.

For e.g. in my case:

```
"expo": "^48.0.0",
"expo-modules-core": "^1.2.3"
```

If package.json not contains these packages install them:

```
npm install expo expo-modules-core
```

Answer (score 0):

this is can help solve all expo related warning and error

In react native:0.73.5,

npm i expo@50.0.0
link manually follow this
link==> https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#using-expo-sdk-packages

after
install==>npm i expo-modules-core (version: "expo-modules-core": "~1.11.10",)

if you use this package then version must be follow=>expon-constant(version:15.4.5),
expo-file-system(version:16.0.8),
expo-font(version:11.10.3),
expo-keep-awake(version:12.8.2)etc.

Answer (score -1):

Faced some issues with iOS build, then **resolved** by fixing incorrect place of `expo_patch_react_imports` on `Profile.lock`. See correct place [there (Expo docs)](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#configuration-for-ios).

Comment: i am facing the same issue, only in iOS, can you tell me what you did ?